# Correct startup sequence for Endeca components?

Tags: atg, endeca, oracle-commerce

So I have created a startup bash script for my local endeca 11.1 environment which is running on Centos 6.6:

```sh
#!/bin/sh


ENDECA_USER=endeca
ENDECA_BASE=/usr/local/endeca
GREEN='\e[32m'
NC='\e[39m' 

source /usr/local/endeca/MDEX/6.5.1/mdex_setup_sh.ini
source /usr/local/endeca/PlatformServices/workspace/setup/installer_sh.ini


echo ER = $ENDECA_ROOT

usage() {
  echo "Usage: ${0} (start|stop)"
}

case "${1}" in
 start)
echo "Starting Endeca ..."
echo -ne "\n\n${GREEN}Starting MDEX Engine ... ${NC} \n\n"
${ENDECA_ROOT}/tools/server/bin/startup.sh
sleep 5
echo -ne "\n\n${GREEN}Starting Platform Services ... ${NC} \n\n"
${ENDECA_BASE}/PlatformServices/11.1.0/tools/server/bin/startup.sh
sleep 5
echo -ne "\n\n${GREEN}Starting Tools & Frameworks ... ${NC} \n\n"
${ENDECA_BASE}/ToolsAndFrameworks/11.1.0/server/bin/startup.sh
sleep 5
${ENDECA_BASE}/CAS/11.1.0/bin/cas-service.sh &
;;
stop)
echo "Shutting down Endeca ..."
${ENDECA_ROOT}/tools/server/bin/shutdown.sh
sleep 5
${ENDECA_BASE}/PlatformServices/11.1.0/tools/server/bin/shutdown.sh
sleep 5
${ENDECA_BASE}/ToolsAndFrameworks/11.1.0/server/bin/shutdown.sh
sleep 5
${ENDECA_BASE}/CAS/11.1.0/bin/cas-service-shutdown.sh
wait
echo "Endeca shutdown complete!"
;;
 *)
    usage
exit 2
esac

  exit $?
```

This script works most of the time does fail on occassions and I want to check what the correct start up sequence is for endeca and if my script needs to wait for each component to start up before I start the next?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: "does fail on occassions" - how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coming from a `Microsoft Windows` environment, only 3 of the for services you list are considered to be services and perhaps this is the issue with you startup/shutdown scripts. The `MDEX` isn't an explicit service. However one or more `d-graphs` will be running on the server where the MDEX component is installed and perhaps this is where the disconnect is.

The `PlatformServices` component should be the most important one and can control stopping and starting the running `d-graphs` (MDEX Engines). Instead of stopping the `MDEX` 'service' you should rather stop the `d-graphs` using the `runcommand.sh` that exists within the individual Endeca Apps' control folder.

So assuming you have your apps deployed in your `$ENDECA_BASE` and the app is called `bated` your script should be something like this.

```
#Stop the Authoring Dgraph
${ENDECA_BASE}/apps/bated/control/runcommand.sh AuthoringDgraph stop
#Stop the additional Dgraphs (as configured in your LiveDgraphCluster.xml)
${ENDECA_BASE}/apps/bated/control/runcommand.sh DgraphA1 stop
```

Once these have been stopped, you can proceed to shut down the `PlatformServices`, `ToolsAndFramework` and `CAS` services, in any order.

Starting up will require starting the above three services again and then again calling the `runncommand.sh` but this time with the `start` parameter. You will need to wait for the `PlatformServices` to be up and running properly before trying to start the `d-graphs`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you. Out of interest what spec PC do you use to run your development environment on? I find that when running Platform Services and Dgraphs I have very high CPU and memory usage

Comment: A dedicated Microsoft Server 2012 R2 VM with 8Gb of RAM and 2x 2.60GHz processors seems plenty for development purposes. We don't do lots of load in this environment (maximum of 12 developer instances connected at any point in time). Biggest 'bottleneck' is actually an underspec database that takes a long time to generate the CAS output for the index.